# How to convert fb2 file in to txt using Python

Tags: python

Hello I am struggling to convert hundreds of fb2 files to txt using Python. I find pyandoc and EbookLib but I didn't find in their functionality this option, or I didn't search carefully.
Can someone suggest me something relevant in my case ? Maybe free API, but I think there could be a library.

Comment: Please share the codes of your attempts

Answer (score 0):

*something relevant in my case*

I did look for `fb2` and `FictionBook2` at PyPI and found 2 potentially useful to you: [catpandoc](https://pypi.org/project/catpandoc/) and [FB2](https://pypi.org/project/FB2/). 1st does *Cat multiple documents to the terminal.* and support numerous file formats. 2nd is *Python package for working with FictionBook2*. For `FB2` example is given how to create `FB2` file, but not how to read. I do not know if it means documentation is poor or it does not have read support at all.

EDIT: After some research I found that [FictionBook2](http://gribuser.ru/xml/fictionbook/index.html.en) files are XML files. Example can be seen [here](http://gribuser.ru/xml/fictionbook/shema_comments.html). That being said I encourage you to first try existing `FB2` tools and *only if they fail* to deliver desired result implement extraction by XML parsing.